# Deleting some rows in a table based on a colum which is a clob data type

Tags: database, oracle11g, clob

I have the below query to delete some data from table A

**delete from TableA where id in (select id from TableB) and text != 'The text has important value';**

But iam getting the below error **ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB**

Here the text column is CLOB datatype.But i need to check the text value and then only i need to delete.

Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Convert/Cast clob to varchar

delete from TableA where id in (select id from TableB) and to_char(text) != 'The text has important value';

```
delete from TableA where id in (select id from TableB) and to_char(text) != 'The text has important value';
```

Comment: While trying the above query iam getting the below error.rror report -
SQL Error: ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 4238, maximum: 4000)
22835. 00000 -  "Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: %s, maximum: %s)"

Comment: use this function to convert UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2()

Answer (score 0):

you can use TO_BLOB('89504E4') to convert char to BLOB

Comment: I need to delete the value actually..!!